# Can't set tabBarItem-title in actionSheet-delegate method

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I'm using the `UIActionSheet`'s method `showFromTabBar:` to display the action-sheet. In the delegate-method `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` I try to change the current `UITabBarItem`'s title by calling `self.tabBarItem.title=@"New Title"`, where `self` is the current TabBarController's ViewController. When I do this, the TabBarItem's title becomes an empty string (""). When I post a `NSNotification` in the action-sheet's delegate-method and try to change the title in the notification-handler method in the same way, the app crashes (without any output on the console). But when I call instead `[self.tabBarItem performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setTitle:) withObject:@"New Title" waitUntilDone:NO]`, it works with both variants. This is a bug in the SDK, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `UIActionSheet` is blocking the main thread (Or at least interaction with it) during the call to `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, probably as a result of being presented by/from the `UITabBar`.

You are essentially scheduling the `setTitle:` task to be completed later with the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:NO` call. And this will work just fine. It's very similar, if not identical to using blocks like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.tabBarItem.title = @"New Title";
});
```

And if that syntax suits you better that's great.

**But there is an easier way.** Just use the delegate method `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` this method is called, as the name suggests, when the `UIActionSheet` has already dismissed, so it will no longer block your other calls.

Comment: +1, because it works with the didDismissWithButtonIndex: method. But your "blocked main-thread" explanation is not satisfactory. What exactly do you mean with the term "blocked" and why does it prohibit the (immediate) setting of a simple title-property?